# Reset total points counter in exsheets

Tags: exsheets

How can I reset the totalpoints counter in exsheets? For example if I create two variants of an exam I usually do this with `includequestions` and `variants` using two files. However if I want to include both variants into one file and want to print the totalpoints it gives me the total points of both variants.

Comment: You can't reliably do this. The points are written to the aux file at the end of the document and read from there. When you reset the number (which is possible using internals) then none of the official commands will give the correct value. It should be doable with https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim though using different types of points for the two variants. Are the two versions simply concatenated or are they intertwined? Because the first is simple with `pdfpages`.

Comment: The two versions are just concatenated, that's why I use two files for this. I think pdfpages doesn't help here. I just wanted to simplify the process by having just one file...

Comment: Yes it does: produce both versions as seperate pdf files and include them both with ?pdfpages` in a third pdf